# Maven cannot create a jar file

Tags: java, maven

I used for building  and creating a jar file this command as l know

```
$ mvn -Pzinc package
```

and that also

```
$ mvn -f m2-pom.xml package
```

and it built successfully !

but i can't find a jar file ?

Comment: Reading about maven a bit may help: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Where is the Storm part in your question?

Comment: i downloaded storm-starter from github then wanted to mvn it but the result of maven got 2 files snapshot like SNAPSHOT-jar-with- dependencies.jar and this SNAPSHOT.jar and i don't know what's snapshot and i thought that jar file should be storm-starter.jar

Comment: You need to read the Maven guide @AlexeyRomanov mentioned.

Comment: i read it now .but i can't understand why it couldn't create file.jar and created snapshot ? i can't got it! or is maven created file snapshot.jar only ?

Comment: Because that's what instructions in the m2-pom.xml file told Maven to do.

Comment: Thanks . so you mean that i should edit in pom.xml to create file.jar and not snapshot ! but do you know how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project's target directory you'll able to see the generated jar file.

Comment: Thanks very much ! i found it. but it have two file SNAPSHOT-jar-with- dependencies and this SNAPSHOT do you know what's the difference between them ?

Comment: You could have a look yourself with `jar tf <filename>`... Hint: one JAR file contains the dependencies, the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for helping . is the file must be ZIP File ? and why mvn didn't create file.jar i mean why it created file_snapshot.jar and file_snapshot-with dependencies.jar?

Comment: Ah... yes. A [JAR file is a ZIP file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29).

Comment: i accepted your answer as i must have 15 reputation to vote up