# Create jar file from maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to create a jar file without SNAPSHOT cause when i used this command

```
mvn -f pom.XML package
```

created two files "file name_SNAPSHOT.jar and file name_SNAPSHOT_WITH_dependencies.jar"
I want file name.jar
i know that i should edit in pom.XML so i tried to add this

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.Apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
   <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>         
      <executions> 
       <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
           <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

but it created file name_SNAPSHOT_source.jar how can i solve it ?!

My pom.XML like that

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <model Version>4.0.0</model Version>
    <group Id>MyProject</group Id>
    <artifact Id>MyProject</artifact Id>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: First can you show your full pom file apart from that change the version in your pom file into something like `1.0` which will produce a jar file without `-SNAPSHOT`. Furthermore you should name your pom file like `pom.xml` and than you can omit `mvn -f pom.XML` from your maven call. Based on what you mentioned it seemed to me you are using maven-assembly-plugin etc. which creates some file.

Comment: sorry i can't understand you well but do you mean that version of maven caused that ? i named file pom.XML i have Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)

Comment: The snippet `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` in your pom file is causing that you get created artifacts with `-SNAPSHOT`. The maven version (2.2.1) does not matter in that case. Change the name of your pom file from `pom.XML` into `pom.xml`.

Comment: it's pom.xml but i wrote it unwitting in post XML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way is to change `project.version`. But this is not recommended because development jar should has version with suffix `-SNAPSHOT`.

> Maven goes a long way to help you with version management and you will often see the **SNAPSHOT designator in a version, which indicates that a project is in a state of development**.

More information:

- [What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)
- [How do I make my first Maven project?](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project)

Other solution without changing `project.version` is to use property `finalName`. This solution removes whole `version` from artifact.

```
<build>
 <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

After applying your `pom.xml` should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.something</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>My Project<name>
  <build>
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Property `finalName` apply also to [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#finalName)

Read also:

- [Controlling maven final name of jar artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)
- [Maven versioning best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554688/maven-versioning-best-practices?lq=1)

Comment: i added this in pom <build>
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  </build>
 and got exception Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Unrecognised tag: 'fileName' (position: START_TAG seen ...<build>\n <fileName>... @12:15)

Comment: sorry i read it quickly .. many thanks it worked successfully i want to vote up but i got this "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 1):

You should definitively [read the Maven documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086076/maven-cannot-create-a-jar-file#comment31727716_21086076). However, the file name is derived from the project's artifact name and version. Your POM might look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.something</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>My Project<name>

...
```

Your file name will be like: `myproject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

The naming convention of Maven artifacts is: `{artifact-name}-{artifact-version}.{artifact.packaging}`.

In order to get rid of the `SNAPSHOT` part, just change the version to `0.1` or any other version you like.

For more information about snapshots, read this: [What exactly is a Maven Snapshot and why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it)

Comment: Thanks,i edited in the post a part of my pom.XML ,so do you mean that i should change number in the tag <version> to any number ? i'll read the link you sent now .many thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. BTW: If my answer(s) help, then you should accept them.

Comment: I want to vote up but i got this "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 1):

To create just the jar with `project-name.jar` and all dependencies included, try to use assembly plugin.

A configuration could look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>{your.main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Make sure to replace `{your.main.class}` with your fully qualified Main class. The jar will be generated in your project root folder instead of target.

Comment: what do you mean by your in  {your.main.class} ?

Comment: OP already has configured `jar-with-dependencies`, the question is about SNAPSHOT :)

Comment: Yes, and this one will exclude it. ;-)

Comment: @user3188912 thats the name of your class with the package prefixed. E.g. `com.foo.bar.Main`

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) is your friend. It will:

1. Update your pom file(s) so that they are no longer -SNAPSHOT
2. Create a tag in your SCM denoting this release version
3. Increment your pom file(s) to the next -SNAPSHOT version

Now all you have to do is checkout the version with the tag, for whichever version you want to build, and run `mvn package` to get your non-snapshot jar.

Alternatively you can of course do all this manually. :)